# Tourist visa vs Visit visa in Romania

Tags: visas, tourist-visas, accommodation, romania

I am from Egypt.

I traveled to Romania once via a visit visa to my girlfriend, the visa required an invitation approved by the IGI.

I would like to travel again but this time, via a tourist visa (as it takes a shorter time) as a surprise visit to her.

The tourist visa requires a proof of accommodation, however, I will supposedly stay in her home, not in a hotel, will that home be acceptable as a form of accommodation?